# Laravel ManyToMany intermediate table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to figure out how to solve the following problem using EloquentORM in Laravel.

I have 3 tables.

```
User:
-id

Agreement:
-id
-title
-date_created

Accepted_Agreements:
-user_id
-agreement_id
-date_accepted
```

So, how can I get all Agreements and the -date_accepted column also for a specific User ?

Comment: define relationship first..agreement has one or many accept_agreement?

Comment: one agreement has only one accepted_agreement

Comment: then relationship should be User hasMany Agreement, Agreement hasOne Accepted_agreement, Accepted_Agreement belongsTo User, Accepteed_Agreement belongsTo Agreement...no need to use manytomany relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose you have defined many-to-many relationships in agreements() and user() functions.

```
public function agreements() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agreement')->withPivot('date_accepted');
}
```

Then you may get the required in the following way:

```
$agreements = $user->agreements;

foreach($agreements as $agreement) {
   $dateAccepted = $agreement->pivot->date_accepted;
}
```

Comment: but this way I won't get ALL agreements, only those that the user accepted.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but in the pivot table only 2 columns are returned, user_id and agreement_id.

Comment: I have updated my answer. To get the intermediate table column you need to specify it in the function where you define the relationship. In the example above this is the agreements() function.